# Thread 3: Fatal error: Index out of range

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make to extract weather data but I get an out of range error. can anyone help? My friend told me its a problem with my array but I was sure to use a string separator.

My main goal is to retrieve the weather data from the website and then add it to a variable called message

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = URL(string: "https://weather.weatherbug.com/weather-forecast/now/salt-lake-city")!
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){
        data, response, error in

        var message = ""
        if  error != nil{
            print(error.debugDescription)
        }else{
            if let unwrappedData = data {
                let dataString = NSString(data: unwrappedData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                var stringSeperator = "<span class=\"value ng-binding ng-scope\" ng-if=\"widget.ObservationAggregate.Observation.FeelsLike\" ng-bind=\"UnitUtility.convertTemp(widget.ObservationAggregate.Observation.FeelsLike)\">"

                if let contentArray = dataString?.components(separatedBy: stringSeperator){
                    if contentArray.count > 0 {
                       stringSeperator = "</span>"

                       let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stringSeperator)

                       if newContentArray.count > 0 {
                           message = newContentArray[0]
                           print(newContentArray[0])
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: `contentArray[1]` could be the problem since you only ensure that `contentArray[0]` would be valid with the line `if contentArray.count > 0`. Change the `0` to `1`.

Comment: Stepping back from your specific question, which others have answered, you're trying to parse HTML (display) data. That's not generally a good idea. There are other weather services that return JSON or other data formats intended to be consumed by a program. A web page is subject to change that will likely break your code, even if you do get it working for the current results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are getting this error on the following line.

```
let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stringSeperator)
```

The problem seems to be that you are checking your `contentArray`'s count to be greater than 0 but accessing index 1. Note here that an array's count being not 0 does not necessitate that it will have a value at index 1. Since the array's index start with 0, index 1 would in fact require your array's count to be at least 2.

Comment: Thanks, I just changed if contentArray.count > 0 to if contentArray.count > 0. I still have the same error

Answer (score 0):

When we want to get some info from a server it is recommended to get/parse a `JSON` or an `XML`. I see you are trying to parse an `HTML` from a website.

After clarifying that, if you don't have alternatives, I think you are reaching to those `error: Index out of range` since you are assuming your data will have always the format you think (normally you need to handle special cases)

You could update your internal validation to this:

```
if contentArray.count > 1 {
         stringSeperator = "</span>"
         let newContentArray = contentArray[1].components(separatedBy: stringSeperator)
         if newContentArray.count > 0 {
            message = newContentArray.first
            print(newContentArray.first)
         }
}
```

You can group those if in a better way but this is just to guide you.

I hope this helps you.